# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException, com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException

Tags: android, android-studio

Fetching this problem in Android Studio.

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I face this problem try this code in build.gradel.

Also, use this library

dependacies{ 'compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'}

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.2.1"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "yours"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1.2"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }  

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Create application class

```
public class YourApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, I will try this. It can be because of  multidex exception.

Comment: First try only this code in build.gradle  dexOptions {        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"    } & let me know.